# Sharepoint site users requesting access to groups

Tags: sharepoint, usergroups

I was wondering if there was a simple way to allow users to request access to specific groups in sharepoint? i.e Users have a button on a page they can click to join or leave a specific group. Allowing them to self serve access?

Ive looked through the literature and cant see anthing obvious.

Kind Regards

Ive tried lookign through the site permissions options but these are centred around site owners adding users not users adding themselves. Ive also tried a number of button set ups but im wondering if i have to set up a power app to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no OOTB or easy way to let users adding permission to themselves.
If you want to realize your needs, I suggest that you can customize your needs through [Partner](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-US/support/?stage=1).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure self service group membership when you create the SharePoint group like this:

[image: Self service group options]

Note how users can request to join or leave the group and requests are setup to auto accept?  That should address your issue.